# Kendo In grid dropdown updating for any click across the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have upgraded our Kendo JS from 2.1008 to 2.516 in our application.

I am using the in grid dropdown editing feature of the Kendo Grid.

In the previous version(2.1008) when we click on the grid cell the drop down loads and only when a new dropdown list item is clicked the `update`  event of the kendo grid is fired.

In the current upgraded version(2.516) when we click on the grid cell the drop down loads and when you click anywhere on the page other than the dropdown the `update` event is fired. i.e. even though I have not changed (not clicked on)  any drop down list item the grids get updated though it just is the same as previous value(unnecessary 'Successfully updated' message is shown).

Please find below code which gets triggered for any click(anywhere on the screen) even if the dropdown is not changed.

```js
MyProject.Base.DataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  serverPaging: true,
  serverSorting: true,
  pageSize: KendoBaseEntity.defaultPageSize,
  autoSync: true,
  schema: {
    data: "d.Response",
    total: "d.Total",
    model: {
      id: "MyId",
      fields: {
        MyId: {
          editable: false
        },
        MyParentColumn: {
          editable: false,
          type: "string"
        },
        MyColumn: {
          editable: isEditable,
          type: "string"
        }

      }
    }
  },
  requestEnd: function(e) {
    KendoBaseEntity.OnUpdateSuccess(e)
    var proxy = new MyProject.Utility.ServiceProxy("MySomeService1");
    proxy.invoke("GetMyData1", {
        "filter": MyProject.Base.SearchFilter
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response != null && response.length > 0) {
          $("#aMyServer").text('_' + response.length + '_ Servers Not Found');
          $("#aMyServer").show();
          $("#aMyServer").attr('data-info', response);
        } else {
          $('#txtRaMyServerListDialog').text('');
          $("#aMyServer").hide();
        }
      }
    );
  },
  requestStart: function(e) {
    if (KendoDisplayPreferences.preventajaxcall) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "MyServices/" + MyProject.Base.ServiceName + ".asmx/" + MyProject.Base.SearchServiceMethod,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: "POST"
    },
    update: {
      url: "MyServices/MyService.asmx/UpdateInGrid",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: "POST"
    },
    parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
      if (data.page != null) {
        MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.Page = data.page > 0 ?
          data.page : MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.Page;
      }
      if (data.take != null) {
        MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.RecordsPerPage = data.take > 0 ?
          data.take : MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.RecordsPerPage;
      }
      if (data.sort != null && data.sort.length > 0) {
        var sortarray = data.sort;
        var sortinput = '';
        if (sortarray.length > 1) {
          $(sortarray).each(function(index, value) {
            var colName = value.field;
            var order = (value.dir == "asc") ?
              "ascending" :
              "descending";

            var resultarray = MyProject.Base.ResultsColumnModel;
            $(resultarray).each(function(index, ele) {
              if (ele != null) {
                if (ele.field != null && ele.field == colName) {
                  colName = ele.attributes.sortname;
                  sortinput = sortinput + colName + ' ' + order + ';';
                }
              }

            });
          });
          MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortColumn = null;
          MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.MultipleSort = sortinput;
        } else {
          var columname = data.sort[0].field;
          columname = columname == "DefaultB" ? "Default B" : columname;
          columname = columname == "DefaultA" ? "Default A" : columname;
          //Defect 2443
          if (columname == "StartDate-EndDate" || columname == "Default A" || columname == "Default B") {
            MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.MultipleSort = null;
            MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortColumn = columname;
            MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortOrder = data.sort[0].dir;
          } else {
            var grid = $("#ResultsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var columns = grid.columns;
            $(columns).each(function(index, value) {
              if (value.field != null && value.field == columname) {
                MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.MultipleSort = null;
                MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortColumn = value.attributes.sortname;
              }
            });
            MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortOrder = data.sort[0].dir;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (somecondition) {
          MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortColumn = null;
          MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.MultipleSort = 'Server.ServerName ascending;DEPLOYMENT_SEQUENCE ascending';
        }
      }
      if (operation == "read") {

        if (MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortColumn == 'ServerName') {
          MyProject.Base.SearchFilter.Options.SortColumn = 'Server.ServerName';
        }
        var inputvar = {
          'filter': MyProject.Base.SearchFilter
        };
        return JSON2.stringify(inputvar)
      }
      if (operation == "update") {
        debugger
        if (data != null) {
          var myId = data.MyId;
          var updateValue = data[KendoDeployment.EditFieldName];
          switch (KendoDeployment.EditFieldName) {
            case "MyColumnAttributes":
              updateValue = data[KendoDeployment.EditFieldName].UserId;
              KendoDeployment.EditFieldName = "MyColumn";
              break;

            case "MyColumn":
              updateValue = data["MyColumnAttributes"].UserId;
              KendoDeployment.EditFieldName = "MyColumn";
          };
          return JSON2.stringify({
            'MyId': myId,
            "updateValue": updateValue,
            "updateField": KendoDeployment.EditFieldName
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The code in the above script which gets called for any click event is

```
if (operation == "update") {
  debugger
  if (data != null) {
    var myId = data.MyId;
    var updateValue = data[KendoDeployment.EditFieldName];
    switch (KendoDeployment.EditFieldName) {
      case "MyColumnAttributes":
        updateValue = data[KendoDeployment.EditFieldName].UserId;
        KendoDeployment.EditFieldName = "MyColumn";
        break;

      case "MyColumn":
        updateValue = data["MyColumnAttributes"].UserId;
        KendoDeployment.EditFieldName = "MyColumn";
    };
    return JSON2.stringify({
      'MyId': myId,
      "updateValue": updateValue,
      "updateField": KendoDeployment.EditFieldName
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone point out where I have to make changes to fix this issue?